# How to add 1 to a javascript variable by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have very little experience with writing javascript and I need help desperately. I need to make so that when a button is clicked the score goes up by one similar to how the cookie clicker game works this is for an Assignment, the end product is to be a game similar to the cookie clicker game.

this is the code I have so far;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Assignment </title>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <strong>Don't Touch The Button</strong>
    </header>

    <div class="game-object">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var clicks = 0;
        </script>
        <button type="button" onClick ="clicks++" id="push"> NO. </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: ah thanks, i never did that way actually :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just an issues with the pasted code.  But you're declaring the same global variable: `clicks` twice.

Comment: Your code already does precisely what you say you want. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code already works. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YdhTQ/) that demonstrates your code in action.

I have added a function to display the click count:

```
function updateClickCount() {
    document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best code-organization-wise to define this function separately:

```
var incrementCount = function(){
    clicks++;
}
```

And then to call that from your onclick:

```
<button type="button" onClick ="incrementCount();" id="push"> NO.</button>
```

And even better, it'd be smart to get rid of all of your inline javascript (AKA "obtrusive" javascript) alltogether, and make an object that will respond to all click events on all of these types of buttons automatically, but that may be above your level at the moment.

You can add this to an external JS file that you include, and make a new "counter" object that automatically fires when the user clicks your button object.

Comment: Ha, was just writing an answer when this popped up, much more elegant =D

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't declare the "clicks" variable

Comment: This should work... I'll take a look at it I apparently am making a stupid error somewhere....

Comment: It's the case of someone wanting everything handed to them instead of taking the concept and learning the syntax themselves.  His problem and the solution have been clearly identified and offered here.

Comment: Yes, this works fine. I'm not sure where you're having a problem. The primary point of my post is to get the OP to abstract their code out of the obtrusive function, as well as solve the problem. Please see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qPsfu/4/

Comment: @dudewad The `increment()` works fine. I'm talking about the `onClick ="function(){clicks++;}"`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inline, but in the long run it is more maintainable to put the function inside your script, if you are going to reuse it later, or if you need to do other things as well  when the button is clicked.

**JS**

```
function onClick(){clicks++;}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onClick ="onClick()" id="push"> NO.</button>
```

Comment: You need to do `onclick()`, `onClick` by itself will do nothing.