# Add a value upon button click

Tags: javascript, html, click

I'm trying to make a button which would add a value while clicking.
I have this code, what is wrong?

```
    <div id="doughnuts">
    </div>
    <div id="button">
    <button>CLICK to +1</button>
    </div>
```

---

```
var doughnut = 0;
window.setInterval(
function () {
     doughnut = doughnut + 1;
     document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut + " doughnuts!";
     }, 1000);

$('button').click(function(){
   doughnut = Number(doughnut) + Number(1);       
});
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing `doughnut` in multiple places? Simplify it by incrementing, and updating the text within the click callback function.

Comment: what should the code do? why is there the `setInterval` function?

Comment: setinterval is for adding +1 value [link](http://taras.ho.ua/game/)

Comment: it will do it each second, and you want additionally be able to add per click?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 1 to a javascript variable by clicking a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956138/how-to-add-1-to-a-javascript-variable-by-clicking-a-button)

Comment: Ok @Tarasovych check out my answer, it should work, and show you some principles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var doughnut = 0;

    // Define a function,
    // which you can reuse for the task (inc & set in the DOM)
    var incrementAndSet = function () {
      doughnut = doughnut + 1;
      document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut + " doughnuts!";
    }
    
    // Reuse the function where you want.
    // increment and set each second
    window.setInterval(incrementAndSet, 1000);
    
    // increment and set on click
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = incrementAndSet;

    // initialize
    incrementAndSet();
```

```html
<div id="doughnuts"></div>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: @Tarasovych I just removed jquery, you don't need it for this task ;)

Comment: maybe Im too bad but here in snippet it works but not at m site, ohh(

Comment: one moment, I'll put

Comment: You problem: the script is run before the divs are rendered.. place the `<script></script>` just before the closing `</body>`otherwise it cant find the div!!! and the button!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider following code: You only need to update the text after clicking on the button, there is no need to create interval to see the changes

```js
var doughnut = 0;

var showText = function() {
   document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut++ + " doughnuts!";
}



$('button').click(function(){
  showText()
});

setInterval(function(){
  showText();
}, 1000);

showText();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="doughnuts">
    </div>
    <div id="button">
    <button>CLICK to +1</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: i need interval to add 1 value each second

Comment: text doesn't display

Comment: How come? Click on the "run code snippet", the text is shown

Answer (score 0):

Close but here: (no need for `Number`

```
var doughnut = 0;
window.setInterval(
  function() {
    doughnut = doughnut + 1;
    document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut + " doughnuts!";
  }, 1000);

$('button').click(function() {
  doughnut = doughnut+1;
});
```

Here is a fiddle to show it DOES work: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/9wdbbu6s/

Comment: Unsure of the down vote, does what is asked (increment on click and every 1000 ms)

Comment: @Tarasovych it seems that your problem is somewhere else, all these snippets work fine. WHat does your console show?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null --- maybe because var firstly is 0?

Comment: In the simplistic example, you have the event handler on "button" so that is ALL buttons on the page (the only one).  You probably meant to actually do some thing like `$('#button').on('click','button',function()...` to target the ID of the div you have, and the click on the button inside that, since the id is unique on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Changing line to

```
$('#doughnuts').html("You have " + (doughnut+1) + " doughnuts!");
  doughnut++;
```

inside on click button will do the work for you.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ymvcauyj/